# mp_reach_nlri bgp Update with 4-byte Community ASN?

Tags: bgp, juniper-junos

I am BGP peering with a Juniper OS router. When starting the connection, my system advertises 4-byte ASN capability, which is accepted by the Juniper router:
    `Jul 28 00:33:00.664202 BGP RECV 4 Byte AS-Path capability (65), as_num 55002`
    `Jul 28 00:33:00.664217 bgp_parse_4byte_aspath_cap():273 AS4-Peer (RECV): 4 byte AS capability received, AS 55002`
    `Jul 28 00:33:00.664296 bgp_4byte_aspath_add_cap():199 AS4-Peer 10.17.206.131 (Internal AS 55002)(SEND): 4 byte AS capability added, AS 55002`

The Juniper router sends back that 4-byte ASN capability:
    `Jul 28 00:33:00.664405 BGP SEND 4 Byte AS-Path capability (65), as_num 55002`

So I think it is safe to say that the two peers have established 4-byte ASN support.

Later on, we try to send a BGP UPDATE message, which includes the mp_reach_nlri attribute. If we send the BGP UPDATE message with a 2-octet AS/4-octet AN Extended Community attribute (ie, type 0x00, Transitive 2-Octet AS-Specific), Juniper router happily accepts. If we send the BGP UPDATE message with a 4-octet AS/2-octet AN Extended Community attribute (ie, type 0x00, Transitive 4-octet AS-Specific), Juniper router complains and rejects it due to "rejected due to the lack of a valid target community".
    `bgp_rcv_nlri: 64999:0:193.193.193.193/96 rejected due to the lack of a valid target community`

Take a look at the two pcap screenshots below. The ONLY difference in communication between the two peers is this single issue: 4-byte AS in the mp_reach_nlri packet, vs 2-byte AS in the mp_reach_nlri packet. The first image is working, the second is not.

Any clues why this is? How can we successfully send a mp_reach_nlri path attribute with a 4-byte AS as the target community?

[image: working pcap]

---

[image: non-working pcap]

Junos version information:
`Model: mx960
Junos: 15.1R7.8
JUNOS OS Kernel 64-bit  [20180310.ba55661_builder_stable_10]`

My router: proprietary; trying to craft our own packets for this BGP peering session

Junos show bgp neighbor:
`Peer: 10.17.206.131+37333 AS 55002 Local: 10.17.205.45+179 AS 55002
  Type: Internal    State: Established    Flags: <Sync RSync>
  Peer supports 4 byte AS extension (peer-as 55002)`

Comment: Please include software versions and configurations of both routers. A ‘show bgp neighbor’ on the juniper can be useful too.

Comment: Added this information. I suppose what I also am looking for is a better understanding of the mp_reach_nlri path attribute. Does it require a valid target community as part of the Bgp UPDATE message? It seems that JunOS insists so. Where is this documented in an RFC? And if so, why does JunOS like the 2-byte AS target community but not the same encoding as a 4-byte AS target community?

Comment: "_My router: proprietary; trying to craft our own packets for this BGP peering session_" Unfortunately, your router is off-topic here. The manufacturer must offer optional, paid support for a device to be on-topic.

Comment: @Ron Thanks for the comment. But I am not asking for help with a router/brand/configuration. I am moreso asking for help with understanding protocol. Why might JunOS think that a BGP UPDATE message mp_reach_nlri with 4-byte ASN target community is invalid?

Comment: How do we know that the proprietary router is actually performing correctly? It may be the Juniper that is acting correctly, and the other router that is misbehaving. We would really need to see the configurations. There are other configurations that can affect thing, but you have not included those. I just don't see anyone helping much with this.

Comment: The other router is probably not acting correctly. What I really need to know is the if-code block in JunOS that prints the error "rejected due to the lack of a valid target community". What is JunOS checking for, in an mp_reach_nlri BGP UPDATE packet, that causes it to determine there is a lack of valid target community?

Comment: Can you expand the MP_REACH_NLRI part of the screen dump? The exact AFI/SAFI of the NLRI might be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue has nothing to do with how Juniper supports 4-byte ASNs or extended communities.  The `rejected due to the lack of a valid target community` log messages is simply telling you that you don't have a routing instance configured with the target you specified.

You said that the *only* thing that changed between your two packet captures was the setting of the route-targets to use 4-byte ASNs.  Which means, that you didn't change the routing-instance targets to match.

I did some basic lab testing to verify (using your examples).

**2-Byte ASN Example**

As you can see, this works as you'd expect.

**R1:**

```
set routing-instances VRF-A vrf-target target:55002:666
```

**R2:**

```
set routing-instances VRF-B vrf-target target:55002:666
```

**R1:**

```
Dec 30 04:31:30.051381 bgp_rcv_nlri: 55002:1111:202.202.202.0/88

root# run show route table VRF-A.inet.0 202.202.202.0/24

VRF-A.inet.0: 5 destinations, 5 routes (5 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

202.202.202.0/24   *[BGP/170] 00:01:06, localpref 100, from 2.2.2.2
                      AS path: 2222 I, validation-state: unverified
                    > to 5.5.5.1 via ge-0/0/0.0, Push 16
```

**4-Byte ASN Example**

Now, I make R2 send route targets with the 4-Byte ASN.

**R1:**

```
set routing-instances VRF-A vrf-target target:55002:666
```

**R2:**

```
set routing-instances VRF-B vrf-target target:55002L:666
```

**R1:**

We see the same error message you see because there is no routing instance configured on the device that uses the new route-target.

```
Dec 30 04:35:35.879678 bgp_rcv_nlri: 55002:1111:202.202.202.0/88 rejected due to the lack of a valid target community
```

Also, no route in the VRF's routing table.

```
[edit]
root# run show route table VRF-A.inet.0 202.202.202.0/24

[edit]
root#
```

Now, for good measure let's change R1 to also use the 4-Byte ASN target.

**R1:**

```
set routing-instances VRF-A vrf-target target:55002L:666

Dec 30 04:41:08.515333 bgp_rcv_nlri: 55002:1111:202.202.202.0/88

root# run show route table VRF-A.inet.0 202.202.202.0/24

VRF-A.inet.0: 5 destinations, 5 routes (5 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

202.202.202.0/24   *[BGP/170] 00:00:56, localpref 100, from 2.2.2.2
                      AS path: 2222 I, validation-state: unverified
                    > to 5.5.5.1 via ge-0/0/0.0, Push 16
```